# Biological concept behind time dilation

Tags: time, relativity, biophysics, inertial-frames, observers

1. What is the exact mechanism which makes aging process slow for persons travelling at higher velocity relatively.
2. How does our body cells responds to gravity and undergo aging?

Comment: In short: There is no biological mechanism, since you yourself don't notice the difference.